# Maui Listview grouping

Tags: c#, listview, maui

I have a list which consists of around 100 object. Each object has 2 properties (name, punch_time). The class is as follows:

```cs
public class Trxs
{
    public string punch_time { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set;}
}
```

the list name is (Punch_Times):

```cs
List<Trxs> Punch_times = new List<Trxs>();
```

It is a finger-print machine transactions. I want to populate a list view in Maui, so that the data will be grouped based on the name, as below:
[It should show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBIDk.png)

I Tried the following grouping of the list, It showed the list grouped but without the group name. The listview name is (Trx_List):

```cs
var sorted = Punch_times.GroupBy(x => x.name)
    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
    .ToList();
        
Trx_List.ItemsSource = sorted ;
```

the result showed like this (the group names are empty):

[But it is showing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLjRU.png)

I have created a class to represent to new list, which will be the item source of the Trx_List as follows:

```cs
public class Grouped_list
{
    public string emp_name { get; set; }
    public List<Trxs> trxes { get; set; }
}
```

And created a new list:

```cs
List<Grouped_list> new_list = new List<Grouped_list>();
```

but how to copy the items from (sorted) to (new_list). Or is it needed? how to make item source of the list view grouped by name?

Any help please!

Thank you

Comment: OK.  Have you read the docs on `LIstView` grouping?  This is pretty straightforward to do and there are many existing questions on the topic.  And please take the time to format your code so it is readable

Comment: I read this Microsoft article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-7.0#display-grouped-data) but I was unable to reflect it to my needs.

Comment: you have not created a class to model the grouped data

Comment: I have created a class to represent to new list, which will be the item source of the Trx_List as follows: `   public class Grouped_list
    {
        public string emp_name { get;  set; }
        public List<Trxs> trxes { get;  set; }

    }`

Comment: the code you posted above does not show you actually using that class

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I forgot to add it. I just did.

Comment: Is `List<Grouped_list>` the type of `sorted`? If not, are you saying that you don't know how to build such a list? There's probably some way to do that in Linq, not coming to my mind right now. Loop through all the items. For each item, see if new_list contains a Grouped_List with matching name. If not there, create such a group, add it to master list. Then add item to the (found or created) group.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I am really new at Maui and C# in general. but Liqun reply solved this issue, which seems to be simple task for pros, but for me, it was driving me crazy      
      ლಠ益ಠ)ლ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Grouped_list : List<Trxs>
{
    public string emp_name { get; set; }

    public Grouped_list(string name, List<Trxs> list) : base(list)
    {
        emp_name = name;
    }
}
```

You need something like that.

And then your observable is:

```
public ObservableCollection<Grouped_list> GroupedLists...
```

Set it as ItemSource, and don't forget to set IsGrouped to true.

In the GroupHeaderTemplate there should be binding to emp_name.
And its DataType should be Grouped_list.

Also, It is EmpName, not emp_name. And GroupedList not Grouped_list.
Follow the naming conventions.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but I have to stick with the listview since I am used to it (◔ д◔). But i will try the collection view later.

Comment: @AbedElHameedJaber the code changes I pointed out, apply for ListView as well. And it is not suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

To be frank, I recommend to use CollectionView instead of ListView. There is a known issue about iOS GroupHeaderTemplate :[ListView GroupHeaderTemplate produces blank headers on iOS and MacCatalyst](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13076). It just render a blank headers. That's why i recommend to use CollectionView. The usage is almost the same. You could  refer to [Display grouped data in a CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping?view=net-maui-7.0).

For your case, how to reflect **sorted** to **new_list** really matters. I made a small demo following the official documentation based on your code.

For **MainPageViewModel.cs**,

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public List<Trxs> Punch_times { get; set; } = new List<Trxs>();
    public List<Grouped_list> new_list { get; set; } = new List<Grouped_list>();
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        //Add some data for test
        Punch_times.Add(new Trxs
        {
            name = "John",
            punch_time = "13:33"
        });
       ......
       // translate list to dict (key is name)
        var dict = Punch_times.GroupBy(o => o.name)
                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Trxs>> item in dict)
        {
            new_list.Add(new Grouped_list(item.Key,new List<Trxs>(item.Value)));
        }
    }
}
```

For **Grouped_list.cs**,

```
public class Grouped_list : List<Trxs>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public Grouped_list(string name, List<Trxs> trxs) : base(trxs)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

For **MainPage.xaml** which consumes the ListView or CollectionView,

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding new_list}" 
      IsGrouped="True">
        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"

                           BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                           FontSize="20"
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding punch_time}" BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                           FontSize="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>                                               
                </StackLayout>                 
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

or you may use ListView but not render correctly on iOS as i mention above.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding new_list}" 
      IsGroupingEnabled="True">
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"

                           BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                           FontSize="20"
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding punch_time}" BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                           FontSize="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>                                               
                </StackLayout>                 
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

For more info, you could refer to [ListView : Display grouped data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-7.0#display-grouped-data) and [Display grouped data in a CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping?view=net-maui-7.0)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Liqun, you are a genius. I have been trying to solve this task for more than 2 days and your code solved my problem. ╰(▔∀▔)╯. But why should the `Grouped_list` inherit from `List<Trxs>`? can't we just make a new list, and copy the values to it directly?

Comment: Thanks for your response@Abed ElHameed Jaber .Each **Grouped_list** item in new_list populate one Group's data in ListView. It should be enumerable for Trxs as each item in DataTemplate would enumerate Grouped_list to get each Trxs instance to populate a line. It just like the ItemSource of ListView should be set to IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: Sorry that now it's too late here. If you have any questions, I will answer tomorrow. And I am not a genius. The question almost took me most of the day. I think the key point for the issue is to change **sorted** to **new_list** which could be consumed by listview.

Comment: Done with pleasure

Comment: I have to clarify that I am not asking for accept. It is completely up to you which answers you select and only you know which answer help you most. I just want my answer could help more people with similar question. Sorry if my words influence your judgement~Happy weekend.

Comment: Hello Liqun. No, your words didn't influence my judgement bro. Your solution actually solved my problem, period.