# Maui group a List<T> and show it in a ListView

Tags: listview, maui, group

I have a list with this structure:

```
public class Words
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public int Word_Order { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Mainmeaning { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Meaning_Group { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Translation { get; set; }
    public string IPAUK { get; set; }
    public string IPAUS { get; set; }
    public string WordForms { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Examples { get; set; }
}
```

Each **Words.Word** can repite n times. I'd like to meke a new List grouped by the by each Word and show it in a ListView where in the main line shows (Word,IPAUK,IPAUS)  and for each word shows Type, Mainmeaning and Translation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the docs on Grouping a ListView?  Is there some specific problem you’re having?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maui Listview grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75440184/maui-listview-grouping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use CollectionView instead of ListView. They are similar with some differences: [CollectionView and ListView differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/?view=net-maui-7.0#collectionview-and-listview-differences). However,There is a known issue about iOS GroupHeaderTemplate :[ListView GroupHeaderTemplate produces blank headers on iOS and MacCatalyst](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13076). It just render a blank headers.That's why i recommend to use CollectionView.

In your case, I suppose that you want the **Words.Word** to be the Group title name. So you could follow the documentation: [Display grouped data in a CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping?view=net-maui-7.0).

First step is to create a type that models a single item. (Is this model Words class?)

Then there should be a WordsGroup class which inherits from the List class.

```
public class WordsGroup : List<Words>
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // this is the group title name


    public WordsGroup(string name, List<Words> words) : base(words)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Also there is an IEnumerable collection of group which ItemSources of Collection should bind to.

```
public List<WordsGroup> WordsGroups { get; private set; } = new List<WordsGroup>();
```

Then we could add group data in many ways. Actually, I don't know how you organize your data. So I cannot give you specific suggestions. Maybe you may refer to [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75444836/20118901)

Also in CollectionView don't forget to set IsGrouped to true.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding WordsGroups}" 
      IsGrouped="True">
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: This is almost identical to the answer you provided to the linked duplicate.  Please vote to close duplicate questions instead of repeating answers.